# How to avoid overlapping HTTP response in a long poll with Obserables?

Tags: angular, observable

I am polling my DB to get the status of a asynchronous job like this:

```
handleProgress(job: AsyncJobDTO) {
    const finished: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
    this.progressService.startProgress();  

    Observable.interval(1000)
      .switchMap(() => this.http.get('/job_url/' + job.id))
      .takeUntil(finished)
      .subscribe((dto: AsyncJobDTO) => {

        if (dto.finishedAt) {
          finished.next();
          this.progressService.stopProgress();         
        }
    })
}
```

This works well.

**How do I prevent the sending the next HTTP request if the last has not responded yet ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a flag, and implement logic as follows.

```
interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
  if (!this.isRequesting) {
    this.isRequesting = true;
    this.http.get('/job_url/' + job.id).subscribe((dto: AsyncJobDTO) => {
      if (dto.finishedAt) {
        finished.next();
        this.progressService.stopProgress();
      }
      this.isRequesting = false;
    }, () => this.isRequesting = false);
  }
})
```

Comment: I thought about such a solution but I was hoping to find some Built-in observable functionality... So I don't need my SwitchMap anymore ?